# How to install no_NO.utf8 local for Centos8

Tags: php, locale, centos8

Unusual sitiation, coming here after hours at Google-remote-office. One of my customers moved from Centos6 to Centos8, and from php5.6 to php7.3 and is now missing Norwegian localization. They use this code to set it in PHP:
'''setlocale(LC_ALL, 'no_NO.UTF-8', 'no_NB.UTF-8');'''

but it's not working, locale is missing on the server. I have installed all possible language packs, it allows to set "no_NO" locale, which is not UTF8 and breaks their scripts.. I was not able to find a solution. Could anyone please help/suggest?

Anton